# Type-infer string buffer

Tags: type-inference

Would it be possible to infer from the usage of a variable if a string buffer would be preferred over an immutable string, or a rope even?

Example, destructive update (thanks, dmbaturin):

```
a[2] = 'b';  // Used as mutable, better use buffer
```

The point being to get higher performant string operations without dumping the details on the programmer.

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: Well, a type-inferred subset of PHP in my case, but it should be possible to discuss generally, I think.